# Canvas - DrawImage Method

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I got a strange problem with the "DrawImage"-Methode of the Canvas element. With the following code I create the canvas and attache it to the "rightcanvas" div.

```
var rightcanvas = document.getElementById('rightcanvas');   
rcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
rcanvas.setAttribute('width', canvasLength);
rcanvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
rcanvas.setAttribute('id', 'rcanvas');
rightcanvas.appendChild(rcanvas);
```

And now I try to draw a Base64 encoded image.

```
var rcontext = rcanvas.getContext('2d');
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBOR....';
rcontext.drawImage(image,0,0);
```

The canvas will be created and attached. But the image will not be displayed.Does somebody know what the problem is? =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for the image to load before drawing it to the canvas.

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    rcontext.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBOR....';
```

Comment: Btw it would be better to avoid naming your variable 'image'.